# UINavigationBar large title not resizing when performing segues

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, preferslargetitles

I've used this code in my main `UIViewController` to have a large title:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

But I don't want that to happen in every view, indeed I just want that large title in my main view.

So, reading online, I've seen that to achieve this I needed to add this in my views in which I did not want that large title:

```
navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
```

But that's not really working as expected.

The result that I'm getting is that when I perform a segue, the title disappears, but the navigation controller maintains the same size as if there was a large title inside it.

What could be wrong with my implementation?

iOS 12.1 Beta 3
Xcode 10.1 Beta 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `largeTitleDisplayMode` to `.never` for the `navigationItem` of your **view controller** instead.

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
```

Alternatively, if you're working with storyboards, you can set the **Large Title** option to **Never** inside the Attributes inspector of your navigation item:

[image: Navigation Item settings - Large Title set to Never]

Comment: Tried that too without success.
`func setupNavigationTitle() {
        navigationItem.title = "Counters";
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true;
        navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never;
    }`

Comment: @matt.logic Please show your exact setup in the question. Also, try to create a view controller setup with just the above mentioned code and see whether the issue persists.

Comment: Ok I've read that incorrectly, that fixed the problem! Many thanks! If I can ask, what is the difference between the navigationController.navigationItem and the simple navigationItem?

Comment: @matt.logic Replace `navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never` with `navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never`, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @matt.logic You welcome! Every `UIViewController` instance has a `navigationItem` property. Since `UINavigationController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, it also has one. However, the navigation item of a view controller in a navigation stack overrides the navigation item of the `UINavigationController` itself (this behavior lets you assign different navigation item titles for every VC in the stack).